# Having an issue with the last part of my Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble with a problem (and yes it is homework).. The question is:

4. Write a `SELECT` statement that returns one row for each customer that has orders with these columns:

The email_address from the Customers table

A count of the number of orders

The total amount for each order (Hint: First, subtract the discount amount from the price. Then, multiply by the quantity.)

Return only those rows where the customer has more than 1 order.
Sort the result set in descending sequence by the sum of the line item amounts.
My query for this part works.  It is:

```
SELECT email_address, COUNT(o.order_id) as number_of_orders, sum((item_price-discount_amount)*quantity) As Total
FROM Customers c JOIN Orders o
ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
JOIN order_items oi on oi.order_id =o.order_id
GROUP BY email_address
HAVING COUNT (o.order_id) > 1
ORDER BY number_of_orders DESC;`
```

After that, I'm supposed to modify that query so that it only counts and totals line items that have an `item_price` value greater than 400.  I can't seem to figure it out.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

BTW, it's the My Guitar Shop database.

Comment: You mean `where oi.item_price > 400`? Are you only supposed to include customers that have more than one order that match that; or still all customers with more than one order, but only include those items in the total?

Comment: All customers with more than one order, but only those items with an item_price greater than 400.

Comment: Have you been taught about case expressions? Which can go inside a `sum()`, to continue the hint theme from the question...

Comment: I have, but in this particular class we aren't there yet.  We're only supposed to be using Aggregate functions and subqueries for this assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add a filter for item_price greater than 400 assuming item_price is part of order_items table.

```
SELECT email_address, COUNT(o.order_id) as number_of_orders, sum((item_price-discount_amount)*quantity) As Total
FROM Customers c JOIN Orders o
ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
JOIN order_items oi on oi.order_id =o.order_id
where oi.item_price > 400
GROUP BY email_address
HAVING COUNT (o.order_id) > 1
ORDER BY number_of_orders DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email_address, COUNT(o.order_id) as number_of_orders, sum((item_price-discount_amount)*quantity) As Total
FROM Customers c JOIN Orders o
ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
JOIN (
    SELECT order_id, 
        CASE WHEN item_price < 400 THEN 0 ELSE item_price END,
        --other columns you need
    FROM order_items ) oi on oi.order_id =o.order_id
GROUP BY email_address
HAVING COUNT (o.order_id) > 1
ORDER BY number_of_orders DESC;
```

This is should work.

Also, you should always use table aliases when addressing a coulmn- even if there are no name clashed. It improves readability and prevent you from making nasty mistakes.